# What is the "true static pressure"?

Tags: arinc-429

What is true static pressure? How do we define it? Is it same as corrected static pressure for installation and errors? 
ARINC 429P1-18 defines Static pressure as corrected and uncorrected where in few places I have heard this term "True static pressure".

Comment: A reference of where you've heard/seen this would be useful, as I'm not familiar with the term

Comment: Aviation and Aeronautical Engineering, Volume 6, Section "Altitude errors in Aerial Navigation".https://books.google.com/books?id=Lm9VAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA624&lpg=PA624&dq=true+static+pressure+in+aviation&source=bl&ots=rEvqiszJXj&sig=CTgrXQyV1pBRU8ql_d9vQGBSDLQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjm-ZXI6pjfAhWq0FQKHWxtBJs4HhDoATAIegQIABAB#v=onepage&q=true%20static%20pressure%20in%20aviation&f=false

Comment: The text you linked to indicates that the "true static pressure" takes into consideration airspeed, position on the aircraft, and air density

Comment: And it also might be beneficial to note that the text is almost a century old, so some of the terminology and error values may be different than those used today

Comment: How is this different from static pressure we get from pitot static tube ? I have never heard this term before. I was working on flare guidance system and they are also using "true static pressure " for computational purpose. So what is this term and why are we using it ?

Comment: Its on label 171 from ADC ....

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see, the "true" static pressure is the measured static pressure corrected for airspeed & position (Static Source Error Correction).

In my copy of ARINC 429 (May 2004) I don't see a label definition that fits this "true static pressure". Label 171 can be used for manufacturer defined data, so I would see if you can get a better answer from the manufacturer of your data source.